# magento 2.3.4 configurable product price difference

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, price

[image]

My problem is in configurable product price display. actual price in my product is 58.

But i select my drop down configurable price display only 53 QR.

Any one help me.

Comment: run reindex and flush cache

Comment: already try this method but not working

Comment: Please explain to me here

Comment: configurable product price did not get correctly. sir please refer the screenshot